# Making DBX recognize booleans with Firebird

Tags: delphi, data-binding, firebird, dbexpress

The Firebird FAQ explains [how to create a BOOLEAN domain](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq12/).  Probably the most interesting part is at the end, where it says:

> If you use a connectivity library like
>   OleDB under .Net, you can override the
>   OleDB provider's GetSchema method, so
>   the DataTables you get from queries
>   have native .Net booleans.

Is there any way to do that with DB Express?  I'm using the DBX driver from http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/, and it would sure be nice to be able to get back TBooleanField instances in my datasets instead of TSmallintField.

Comment: You can do this manually. Is that good enough?

Comment: It would be if I knew how.  But if I did, I wouldn't have to ask here...

Comment: Right click fields editor, "New field", fill out the controls. I wasn't sure if you were asking how to do this or how to make it happen automatically when you add all fields.

Comment: Oh, I see.  No, I'm trying to make it happen automatically when I retrieve an arbitrary query result.

Comment: I don't know how to do it off the top of my head, but IBX does it (for string fields; it substitutes `TIBStringField`) and you have the source for that....

Comment: I just looked at that.  It only works because InterBase returns something DBX already knows is supposed to be a string.  The problem here is that Firebird doesn't have a Boolean type, so the solution will probably have to be at a lower level.  But that's a starting point, at least.  I'll look a bit deeper...

Answer (score 0):

It is handled by these two methods that each TDataSet descendant can override:

```
function TDataSet.GetFieldClass(FieldType: TFieldType): TFieldClass;
begin
  Result := DefaultFieldClasses[FieldType];
end;

function TDataSet.GetFieldClass(FieldDef: TFieldDef): TFieldClass;
begin
  Result := GetFieldClass(FieldDef.DataType);
end;
```

--jeroen

Comment: This is basically the same thing as Craig suggested.  That will only work with data types that the DBX driver already recognizes.  What I need is to teach it a new type, so it will generate TFieldDef objects whose data type is boolean in the first place.

Comment: I think you can examine the TFieldDef to see what underlying meta information it contains (BOOLEAN is a domain holding only values 0 and 1, or can be NULL). I didn't have time to try this yet because I got family over; first chance  will be after the holiday season.